# Limiting the number of commits getting queried in LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm doing a loop:

```
using LibGit2Sharp;

var filter = new Filter { Since = repo.Refs };
IEnumerable<Commit> commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter);

foreach (Commit commit in commits)
{
     //Do stuff...
}
```

It works fine, but is there a way I can limit the number of results? For example, I'd like to get the newest 100 commits, and forget about the older ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using LINQ's [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

```
var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new LibGit2Sharp.CommitFilter{ Since = repo.Refs });
foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit commit in commits.Take(100))
{
    //...
}
```

Checking the code of [CommitCollection](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/CommitCollection.cs) it seems it will really just return 100 commits (so it don't lookup all then take 100).

And you can set the required sort order with the `Filter.SortBy` property.

Comment: Is this good performance wise? I.e. will it still fetch the rest?

Comment: I think it is OK. That's what I meant on "so it don't lookup all then take 100", so it won't fetch the rest because they implemented a lazy `CommitEnumerator` not just returning all the commits in a big list.